# Problem to run a check in my database in django

Tags: django, function, model, task

I have created a model called Certs, the models is registered and it is showing in the admin page, however I am trying to call it to run a check and try to make a task, but I am getting the error: **No module named 'ships'**,

This is the structure of my project (note I am writing the code in reminders.py):

[image]

And here my code:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from ships.models import Certs
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


b = Certs.objects.count()
def notifications():
    for dates in range(b):
        if Certs.exp_date[b] <= datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30):
            send_mail(subject='Test',message='This is a reminder where you will be reminded about expiring certifications', recipient_list=['info@intermaritime.org'])
```

Thank you very much

Comment: on file settings,py, under INSTALLED_APPS try to include 'ships.apps.shipsConfig'

Answer (score 0):

Add the ships module to your INSTALLED section of settings.py

Comment: I did since the beginning.

Comment: Can you provide your settings.py?